# 3ds Max Rigs to Cinema 4D

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, fbx, rigging, cinema-4d

I exported the rig from 3ds Max as a FBX file and opened it with Cinema 4D. Everything works great, but the model and a different look to it. Also the mask on her head has a different texture, but it was imported with only 1 object. Just wondering if it can be fixed, if not its ok.

Comment: Added a phong tag and its all fixed now :), but the mask texture isnt :/

Comment: Unfortunately, the images you've linked don't appear to work, the images showed as broken icons. (I removed the links because the image sharing site you were using likes to download its client to your machine, without much warning). However, since you're dealing strictly with 3D applications, and there isn't actually any game development involved, I suggest you ask either on the 3DS Max forums or the Cinema 4D forums. As it stands, I think this question is off topic here.